# Dual Rubber Ducky antennas

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, ht, phased-array, citizens-band

Can I use 2 identical rubber ducky antennas with a splitter on my CB HT radio to improve range?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically yes, if you carefully control the lengths of the cables and the placement of the antennas. This is called a [phased array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array).

However, you would get a far better improvement in range by using an antenna which is not a rubber ducky, like a 1/4 wave whip or a dipole. Rubber ducky antennas are electrically shortened, making them smaller. The price of that reduction in size is reduced efficiency.

Comment: And on an HT, it would be a large (~9' long) and cumbersome thing, considerably heavier than the HT.